# Get a string from bytes until null

Tags: python

Given a bytes object and an index, I want to read a string from the bytes between the index and the next null(\x00). For example:

```
bstr=b'abc\x00defg'
addr_to_str(bstr,0) # 'abc'
addr_to_str(bstr,1) # 'bc'
addr_to_str(bstr,4) # 'defg'
```

I can do the following:

```
def addr_to_str(bstr,i):
    return bstr[i:].split(b'\x00')[0].decode('utf-8')
```

Since the bytes object is very large, I would like an efficient version of `addr_to_str`. I am new to Python and not knowing how the interpreter treats the `split()` call when I only want to access the first split result. Or is the `.decode()` necessary?

**Question:** Is there a better and pythonic way to do `addr_to_str()`?

Comment: [`bytes.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#bytes.split) has an optional `maxsplit` argument...or you could use [`bytes.partition()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=partition#bytes.partition) which only does one.

Answer (score 1):

How about (in Python 2):

```
def addr_to_str(s, pos):
   end = s.find('\0', pos + 1)
   if end != -1:
      return s[pos:end]
   else:
      return s[pos:]
```

This scans the string once looking for a null, and then creates a slice.

Comment: `s` is a bytes not a string. It complains s.find('\0',). The function should take a bytes and return a string.

Comment: Works for me in Python 2.7. If you're using Python 3, you might want to specify that.

Comment: So, in Python 3, seem that the .decode() needs to be explicitly called.

Comment: In python 3, for bytes, use `s.find(b'\0', pos + 1)`